# Highcharts Node.js export server : Connection error

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, curl, highcharts

I am trying to create a functionality of exporting a pdf, rendering the chart created using Highcharts in my webpage. I am using Highcharts' export server for creating chart image. I have followed the steps from below link:

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server

I have used Node.js export server following below url:

https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server

Now the issue is, I am not able to generate the image using below command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile":{"title": {"text": "Steep Chart"}, "xAxis": {"categories": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]}, "series": [{"data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}}' 127.0.0.1:7801 -o mychart.png
```

In the result of above command, I am getting this error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 7801: Connection refused
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add server configuration file.

Comment: @DeividasKaržinauskas : I am not getting your point. Can you please explain?

Comment: well, your connection to the localhost is failing, so I'm asking for a server configuration file to check if the server is setup correctly.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. And @DeividasKaržinauskas there is no server configuration file. The server is launched from the terminal with parameters specifying host, port, and that's about it

Comment: Have you enabled the server? It looks like your server is not running. Command for enabling is `highcharts-export-server --enableServer 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you the server is already running.

`highcharts-export-server -enableServer 1 -port 7801`

If it still failing, make sure you are connecting to the correct IP and port.